# Swift Popover Dismisses Inappropriately for iPhone 8 Plus

Tags: ios, swift

On the iPhone 8 Plus, a popover view controller is dismissing every time users touch inside the view (like when a user touches a button from the view controller), and nothing happens when user touch outside the view (when we would expect it to dismiss). When testing against the iPhone 6s and a couple iPad, the app behaves as expected.

The popover is created programmatically with the following Swift code:

```
let selectionViewController =  SelectionTableViewController()
selectionViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
selectionViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)

let popoverViewController = selectionViewController.popoverPresentationController
popoverViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
popoverViewController?.delegate = self
popoverViewController?.sourceView = self.titleView
popoverViewController?.sourceRect = self.titleView.bounds

self.present(selectionViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Additionally, the adaptive presentation style is adjusted to keep consistent behavior on iPhones as iPad:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I have added a simplified version of the app that's recreating the issue to github:
https://github.com/Brandogs/PopoverIssue

Comment: Your `sourceRect` is incorrect (that may not be the cause of the issue, but it needs fixing)

Comment: @matt Touching anywhere inside the popover (button, table view cell, blank space) will cause the popover to dismiss. Touching anywhere outside does not dismiss. Thanks for the sourceRect tip!

Comment: @matt I updated sourceRect to reference self.titleView.bounds. The issue still persists, but that code was still very weird. Thanks again for pointing that out.

Comment: @matt The popover view controller got stacked behind the other view and navigation controllers, which I thought was a little odd but that might be normal. Otherwise, all the the view placements and everything like that looks normal. Yeah, I thought it could be that runtime didn't understand the popover is too, but it seems like if that were the case, there would a misplaces rectangle that doesn't dismiss the popover. Instead, it is the entire area outside of the popover, as if the normal behavior was somehow flipped.

Comment: @matt I uploaded a simplified project recreating the issue to GitHub and put the the link in the original post.

Comment: Let me take a quick peek!

Comment: Can't reproduce. I can tap the big title view to summon the popover. When I tap inside the popover (empty table in front), nothing happens. When I tap outside the popover (empty table in back), the popover vanishes. Just like you'd expect.

Comment: And I can "scroll" (bounce) both empty tables, they seem to be working fine.

Comment: @matt I just realized the issue occurs for specific devices. I am seeing the odd behavior for the iPhone 8 Plus. However, I just tested against an iPhone 6s and a couple iPads and it behaved normally.

Comment: OK, let me try the iPhone 8 plus, hold on a sec

Comment: Tried on iPhone 8 plus, still can't reproduce, all seems to work normally for me

Comment: @matt This is so weird... I have tried on multiple other iOS devices, and can't recreate the issue on anything except the iPhone 8 Plus. I tried "Erase All Contents and Settings..." for the Simulator and cleaning the project, but I'm still getting the same backwards behavior consistently on that single device for both our actual project and the example project I uploaded to github. I guess this is just to some weird environment specific issue, but I would have thought clearing the simulator would have resolved that. Thanks again for all your help today!

Comment: Desperate idea: Try actually deleting this simulator and creating a whole new simulator. In fact, I frequently delete _all_ simulators and create them anew, and especially after an Xcode update.

Comment: @matt You nailed it! I deleted everything from /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/ and the problem disappeared! If you want to write up a quick answer to this issue, I'd love to give you credit for solving the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this particular simulator was just hosed. I recommended this, in a comment:

> Try actually deleting this simulator and creating a whole new simulator. In fact, I frequently delete all simulators and create them anew, and especially after an Xcode update.

The OP did that and presto, the app started behaving correctly.

This was a very weird problem; I've never heard of anything like it!

Comment: Odd but deleting simulator works for me!